# Updating an Azure Board Work Item picklist field

Tags: azure-devops, field, azure-boards, picklist

If I create a new work item "picklist" field and add a few items to it, am I able to update that picklist at a later time to add additional items? If not, how do others handle what seems to be a normal use case?

Example: Create a picklist named "Sales Area" and add "USA, Mexico, and Canada" as valid items. Next month we handle sales in "Europe" so I want to add that to my picklist.

Answer (score 2):

1.Enter organization setting page.

2.From the Process page of the selected inherited process, choose the work item type you want to add the custom field to.
Here we choose the Bug WIT. Note the breadcrumb links that allow you to move back to All Processes and MyAgile process page.
[image]

If the New field and other options are disabled, you don't have the necessary permissions to edit the process. See [Set permissions and access for work tracking, Customize an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#customize-an-inherited-process).

3.Select your target field and edit it
[image]

4.Add your value and save it
[image]